# SCSS: Check if the element has the attribute

Tags: if-statement, sass, attributes, exists

I need to check if the element has an attribute for the styles to apply on mobile devices(or in responsive mode). For example:

```html
<tr>
    <td>Some text here</td>
    <td data-content="Hello there">Other text here</td>
    <td data-content="Hi there">Final text here</td>
</tr>
```

Browser:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Some text here | Other text here | Final text here |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Mobile devices (Required output):

```
--------------------------------
| Some text here               |
| Hello there: Other text here | 
| Hi there: Final text here    |
--------------------------------
```

SCSS:

```
tr {
    td {
        ...

        @if (&[data-content]) {
            &:before {
                content: attr(data-content) ":";
                float: left;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin: 0 5px 0 0;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mobile devices (Current output):

```
--------------------------------
| : Some text here             |
| Hello there: Other text here | 
| Hi there: Final text here    |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: You don't need if here at all, just define the style within a mediaquery.

Comment: Tried that, in fact the `SCSS` code is actually from the media-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently it was quite easy...

SCSS:

```
tr {
    td {
        ...

        &[data-content] {
            &:before {
                content: attr(data-content) ":";
                float: left;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin: 0 5px 0 0;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current output:

```
--------------------------------
| Some text here               |
| Hello there: Other text here | 
| Hi there: Final text here    |
--------------------------------
```